# How to get contents of whole screen in Vim?

Tags: vim, screen

I need to get a copy of screen in Vim. Not a buffer, window, tab, but a whole screen, i.e. if terminal size is 80x25, then I need a string of 2000 characters. Colors do not matter (though, if it is possible, I'd be happy to have this data too). Portable solution (i.e. vimscript only, or maybe some python trick) is welcome.

Comment: If colors don't matter, you can simply select the whole terminal window with the mouse or your terminal emulator's "Select all" feature and copy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to do this with a script, not manually. Vimscript, python, does not matter.

Comment: You should say so in your question.

Comment: `i.e. vimscript only, or maybe some python trick` -- this is from my question.

Comment: "is welcome" doesn't mean "is required". Also what do you want to do with that screendump? Do you want text with escape characters or would HTML be an acceptable output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ScreenShot plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1552) allows you to make a copy of the current Vim view (all window splits, statuslines, etc., including syntax highlighting) as an HTML file.

You can probably "downgrade" the implementation to yield simple text, or postprocess the generated HTML into text.

Comment: Excellent starting point to create what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you want, and I'm not sure what you want to do with the string once you have it.

But here is a function that returns the visible text from each window in a list of strings. It uses the `w0` and `w$` line marks to extract the visible range, yanks the range to register `a`, and dumps the register in the returned list. (The existing a register is saved and restored at the end.)

```
function! WindowStrings()
    let areg = getreg('a')
    let atype = getregtype('a')
    let strings = []
    windo exe ':' . line("w0") . ',' . line("w$") . 'yank a' |
        \ call add(strings,getreg('a'))
    call setreg('a',areg,atype)
    return strings
endfunction
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. This is the hard way I'd like to avoid since it has to be extended to include status line, tabline, window separators, foldcolumn, line numbers (if these features are enabled), i.e. to draw whole screen from scratch.